# How do I specify a new package configuration location using the /Set parameter when using dtexec?

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I'm using dtexec to run an SSIS package from the command line. According to this page: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162810.aspx I should be able to change the location that the package loads design-time configurations from using the /Set parameter. Here is the relevant text:

> You can use the /Set option to change the location from which package configurations are loaded. However, you cannot use the /Set option to override a value that was specified by a configuration at design time. To understand how package configurations are applied, see Package Configurations and Behavior Changes to Integration Services Features in SQL Server 2008 R2.

However, I have no idea what the syntax for this is. The only examples I can find online are for using /Set to change variable values. How do I use /Set to specify a different location for my package configurations?

### Notes:

- The package is a raw file on the file system, it is not installed on a server or in a package store.
- Similarly, the config file I want to use is also just a plain file in the filesystem.
- I am aware that I can run my ssis packages in other ways (install it to a server, use SQL agent etc.) but due to operating environment limitations I have to use dtexec on the command line.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I have the exact same issue and am finding the documentation woefully inadequate and very confusing.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to use the `/Conf[igFile] filespec` option to specify the location of your configuration file.  The `/Set` options is used to alter design-time and configuration values for variables, properties, etc.  The document in your link shows this example for configuration files:

```
dtexec /f "c:\pkgOne.dtsx" /conf "c:\pkgOneConfig.cfg"
```

If you do need to change a variable value at runtime, you could do the following:

```
dtexec /f "c:\pkgOne.dtsx" /conf "c:\pkgOneConfig.cfg" /SET \package\DataFlowTask.Variables[User::MyVariable].Value;newValue
```

Comment: I think you're half right. Using /conf works, but only when specifying variables etc. that do NOT appear in the design-time config. See here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb500430.aspx

Comment: I wasn't aware of that change from 2005 to 2008.  I will fix my answer.